# $facet \ $bucket date manipulation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using $facet aggregation for e-commerce style platform.

for this case I have an products collections, and the product schema contain many fields.

I am using same aggregation process to get all the required facets.
the question is, if I am able to use the same $facet \ $bucket aggrigation to group documents by manipulation of specific field -
for example - in product schema I have releaseDate field which is Date (type) field.

currently the aggregation query is looking like this:

```
let facetsBodyExample = {
    'facetName': [
        { $unwind: `$${fieldData.key}` },
        { $sortByCount: `$${fieldData.key}` }
    ],
    'facetName2': [
        { $unwind: `$${fieldData.key}` },
        { $sortByCount: `$${fieldData.key}` }
    ],
    ...,
    ...
};

let results = await Product.aggregate({
    $facet: facetsBodyExample
});
```

the documents looks like

```
{
    _id : 'as5d16as1d65sa65d165as1d',
    name : 'product name',
    releaseDate: '2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    field1:13,
    field2:[1,2,3],
    field3:'abx',
    ...
}
```

I want to create custom facets (groups) by quarter + year in format like 'QQ/YYY', without defining any boundaries.

now, I am getting groups of exact match of date, and I want to group them into quarter + year groups, if possible in the same $facet aggregation.

Query result of the date field I want to customize:

```
    CURRENT:
    {
        relaseDate: [
            { "_id": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "count": 26 },
            { "_id": "2013-04-01T00:00:00.000Z", "count": 25 },
            { "_id": "2013-07-01T00:00:00.000Z", "count": 23 },
            ...
        ]
    }

    DESIRED: 
    {
        relaseDate: [
            { "_id": "Q1/2014", "count": 100 },
            { "_id": "Q2/2014", "count": 200 },
            { "_id": "Q3/2016", "count": 300 },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

Thanks !!

Comment: And your current pipeline stages and data looks like what? Nothing at all in your question except a few paragraphs about what you want. Show you work so far, show some documents to work with, and show a desired outcome obtainable from the data provided. Most importantly explain which part is your actual problem.

Comment: Hi Neil, Thanks for your comment, I added more description and examples of current state and desired results.